# How to filter on a large list in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-foundation

Somebody asked this question, what will be proper answer for this?

There is a list having 50,000 records, now there is a custom web part which wants to show only top 5 five records. How can we implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the List View Web Part that you want to manipulate to show only 5 records, you start by editing the web part and **edit the current view**. Clicking the link will get to the edit view page, where you can filter, sort and limit the number of records returned in you view, which will be used by your web part.

[image]

Comment: do u think top 5 is possible by LVWP? I think for this query is required?

Comment: Dear Benny, I have another question for you. Does any professional company really keep 50000 records in a list when already there is threshold in-place? How do they overcome this problem?

Comment: @Mdh22 A list can keep up to 30'000'000 item in the list, if they want to, so 50'000 items isn't uncommon. But you need to facilitate sort, filter and pagination to make it work OK.

Comment: If we have set threshold, then how can we bypass threshold issue & keep large value in the list?